# Camera2 face detection without mlkit

Tags: android, face-detection, android-camera2, firebase-mlkit

we were using camerax with mlkit for face detection. but now we need to move our face detection module to the dynamic feature module and mlkit is currently not supported. it is crashing at run time.

now I'm looking for a solution where I don't want to use firebase mlkit. is it possible to use camera2 API to detect faces and draw face rectangle on preview?.

Comment: There should not be any crash when using dynamic feature modules. Can you share the exact exception / crash you are running into (e.g. output you get with 'adb logcat'). This will help us debug this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, you can use android.media.FaceDetector to detect face. We made some changes to Firebase ML Kit to better distinguish the on-device APIs from cloud based APIs. "ML Kit"(without firebase branding) contains all the on-device APIs. see https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection.  Currently, dynamic module delivery is not supported but we are going to add the support.

Comment: Yes, I have used the new mlkit, but as it is not supported for the dynamic module, I've skipped it. I have successfully done the face detection using camera 2 API. but I'm not able to draw a rectangle using the Face object. Here is my repo
https://github.com/happysingh23828/Camera2-face-detection